# Harmonic and analytic function on complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

If $f(z) = u(x, y)+ iv(x, y)$ is an analytic function in a domain $D$ and $f(z) \ne 0$
for all $z \in D$, show that $φ(x, y) = \ln |f(z)|$ is harmonic in $D$.

The above question was taken from Dennis Zill Complex Analysis Chapter 3.3 any help on demonstrating it would be great.

Comment: If $f(z) = 0$ then $\ln \vert f(z) \vert$ isn't defined.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(z) \ne 0$?

Comment: In fact, I edited your question to read $f(z) = 0$.  Now it makes sense.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Typo.$\,\,\,$

Comment: thanks @RobertLewis

Comment: @AmontDiaz: my pleasure my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z) = \log z$.

$$g(f(z)) = \log f(z) = \ln |f(z)| + i \arg f(z)$$

Since $f(z) \ne 0$, there is a neighborhood around $f(z)$ away from the origin and we can take a branch of the logarithm that does not go through this neighborhood.

So $g(f(z))$ is holomorphic in this neighborhood, and $\ln |f(z)|$ is the real part of a holomorphic function, thus it is harmonic.